# C++ SFML src/Utility/FileSystem.hpp:8:36: fatal error

Tags: c++, c, c++11, sfml

I tried to install SFML with the help of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEGLsHp2bw0) because I couldn't find a way to install it myself. After I did `CTRL + B` and `Run build & debug` I got this error:

```
⬤  Build & Run: Debug (target: sfml-vscode-boilerplate.exe)

   src/PCH.hpp
In file included from src/PCH.hpp:66:0:
src/Utility/FileSystem.hpp:8:36: fatal error: experimental/filesystem: No such file or directory
  #include <experimental/filesystem>
                                    ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:313: recipe for target 'bin/Debug/obj/PCH.hpp.gch' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [bin/Debug/obj/PCH.hpp.gch] Error 1
Makefile:262: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

✘  Failed!
   Review the compile errors above.
```

I'm using Windows 10, g++ version 6.3.0, SFML version 2.5.1, Visual Studo Code

Comment: Your compiler is probably too old to support `filesystem`, consider upgrading.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details (which, what version) on your OS, your compiler, and your IDE. Did you read the appropriate tutorial from SFML's website? If not, why not? If so, did you try to follow it?

Comment: I've installed newest version of Mingw and g++.

Comment: The newest version is 11.2 installed via https://www.msys2.org/ for me `gcc --version` from the mingw64 terminal on windows 10 returns `gcc.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0`

Comment: Also for me its `#include <filesystem>` not `#include <experimental/filesystem>` as the current version of mingw supports c++17 and c++20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it was just bad version of GCC and G++